# Get Min and MAX of rows in a timestamp when there is a down

Tags: php, sql, max, min, between

I have a result like this:

```
<?php
    // 56.39 Spending
    // 54.35 Spending
    // 52.32 Spending
    // 50.30 Spending
    // 48.29 Spending
    // 46.29 Spending
    // 44.27 Spending
    // 42.25 Spending
    // 40.23 Spending
    // 38.22 Spending
    // 36.19 Spending
    // 34.19 Spending
    // 32.15 Spending
    // 34.66 Loading
    // 36.99 Loading
    // 38.99 Loading
    // 40.01 Loading
    // 42.03 Loading
    // 44.04 Loading
    // 46.10 Loading
    // 48.12 Loading
    // 50.19 Loading
    // 52.22 Loading
    // 54.26 Loading
    // 56.27 Loading
    // 58.30 Loading
    // 60.32 Loading
    // 62.34 Loading
    // 64.40 Loading
    // 66.42 Loading
    // 68.50 Loading
    // 70.51 Loading
    // 72.55 Loading
    // 74.57 Loading
    // 76.60 Loading
    // 74.57 Spending
    // 72.55 Spending
    // 70.53 Spending
    // 68.53 Spending
    // 66.53 Spending
    // 64.43 Spending
    // 62.12 Spending
?>
```

Values are stored in a table with timestamp.
So, in a day we can have periods of spending and loading.
The values are in Percentage.

The goal is to find the diference between `MIN` and `MAX` of each `Spending` and IGNORE the `LOADING`.

So, in this case I have a total of

```
56,39-32,15 = 24,24% SPENT
+
74,57-60,12 = 14,45%
```

TOTAL SPENT IN **THIS day** was 24,24+14,45 = 38,69%

How can I make this in PHP?

```
The table is like | TIMESTAMP | VALUE
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome Eduardo, how did you pick 56,39 and 32,15?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here, it would probably help if you explained your problem in more detail.

Comment: My database only has 2 rows:
Timestamp and a value.

Those values are going up or going down.

In a certain timeperiod (never know) the values are going down... It's the "spending" time as I can call.

Then, we have to refill and the values start to go up.. when it stops going up, it starts to enter the SPENDING time again.

So, 56,39 was the fisrt value close to midnight. it was spending until 32,15%
Then, we have to refill the tank because the next value is higher. until 76,60%

So I have to calculate the amount of percentage spent in that day (all those rows are from one day

Comment: 56,39 and 32,15 is the first moment of the day that we know there was a spending time. I have to calculate that. 
And later there was another moment... We have to find the diference between them 2 and add it to get the total spent in that day = 74.57 and 62.12

Comment: Looks liek an islands and gaps problem.. First you need to uniquely identify each group of spending, then you can get the averages where spending

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem. You can do this all in SQL.

The key is identifying groups of "spending" that are adjacent.  The difference of row numbers is a convenient approach.  The rest is just aggregating first each "island" and then within a day:

```
select dte, sum(max_spending - min_spending)
from (select date(timestamp) as dte, min(timestamp) as min_ts, max(timestamp) as max_ts,
             min(value) as min_spending, max(value) as max_spending
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by date(timestamp) order by timestamp) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by date(timestamp), type order by timestamp) as seqnum_s
            from t
           ) t
      where value = 'SPENDING'
      group by date(timestamp), seqnum - seqnum_s
     ) t
group by dte;
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  If you look at the innermost subquery, you will see the two sequential numbers.  You should also be able to see that the difference is constant when the values are adjacent in the original data.

Comment: I don't understand your query: type='SPENDING'

I don't have that column. The words Spending and Loading are just comments so you could undertstand that if level are going down, it's spending... if level are going up it's loading.